# Android Spreadsheets api and OAuth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use the spreadsheets api but i dont know how to properly use the credentials. Can someone point me to a complete example where using OAuth2?

I have read some examples and explanations, but while some dont even use credentials others use the CLIENT_SERCRET wich developers console doesnt give me when creating the CLIENT_ID.

I have this simple code right now, i just need to add the credentials.

```
public class OAuth2 extends Application{

static SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("UbicacionDeSordos");

public OAuth2(){

           SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final String email = settings.getString("email", null);

            try {
                String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        this,
                        email,
                        "oauth2:https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");

                        service.setAuthSubToken(token);

            } catch (IOException transientEx) {


            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {


            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {


            }

            }   

public static SpreadsheetService getService(){      
    return service;

}

}
```